Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc
java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to create brand tokens\r\n\tat com.scripledger.services.SolanaService.lambda$createBrandToken$4(SolanaService.java:191)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromItemSupplier.subscribe(UniCreateFromItemSupplier.java:28)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni.subscribe(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:25)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.performInnerSubscription(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:81)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransformToUni$UniOnItemTransformToUniProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransformToUni.java:57)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.UniOnItemTransform$UniOnItemTransformProcessor.onItem(UniOnItemTransform.java:43)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromPublisher$PublisherSubscriber.onComplete(UniCreateFromPublisher.java:86)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.subscription.MultiSubscriberAdapter.onCompletion(MultiSubscriberAdapter.java:37)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiEmitOnOp$MultiEmitOnProcessor.isDoneOrCancelled(MultiEmitOnOp.java:248)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.multi.MultiEmitOnOp$MultiEmitOnProcessor.run(MultiEmitOnOp.java:188)\r\n\tat io.quarkus.mongodb.impl.Wrappers.lambda$toMulti$2(Wrappers.java:32)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:279)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.dispatch(ContextInternal.java:261)\r\n\tat io.vertx.core.impl.ContextInternal.lambda$runOnContext$0(ContextInternal.java:59)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.runTask(AbstractEventExecutor.java:173)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:166)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:470)\r\n\tat io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:569)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:997)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)\r\n\tat io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:842)\r\nCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Transaction failed\r\n\tat com.scripledger.services.SolanaService.lambda$sendTransaction$7(SolanaService.java:215)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualConsumer.accept(SlowContextualConsumer.java:21)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.helpers.UniCallbackSubscriber.onFailure(UniCallbackSubscriber.java:62)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromItemSupplier.subscribe(UniCreateFromItemSupplier.java:31)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.AbstractUni.subscribe(AbstractUni.java:36)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.withSubscriber(UniSubscribe.java:51)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:110)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.groups.UniSubscribe.with(UniSubscribe.java:88)\r\n\tat com.scripledger.services.SolanaService.sendTransaction(SolanaService.java:211)\r\n\tat com.scripledger.services.SolanaService.lambda$createBrandToken$4(SolanaService.java:181)\r\n\t... 26 more\r\nCaused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to send transaction\r\n\tat com.scripledger.services.SolanaService.lambda$sendTransaction$5(SolanaService.java:206)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.context.impl.wrappers.SlowContextualSupplier.get(SlowContextualSupplier.java:21)\r\n\tat io.smallrye.mutiny.operators.uni.builders.UniCreateFromItemSupplier.subscribe(UniCreateFromItemSupplier.java:28)\r\n\t... 32 more\r\nCaused by: org.p2p.solanaj.rpc.RpcException: Transaction simulation failed: Error processing Instruction 1: custom program error: 0xc\r\n\tat org.p2p.solanaj.rpc.RpcClient.call(RpcClient.java:51)\r\n\tat org.p2p.solanaj.rpc.RpcApi.sendTransaction(RpcApi.java:51)\r\n\tat com.scripledger.services.SolanaService.lambda$sendTransaction$5(SolanaService.java:201)\r\n\t... 34 more
   public Uni<Uni<String>> createBrandToken(String ownerPublicKeyStr, Long initialSupply) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
            try {
                PublicKey ownerPublicKey = new PublicKey(ownerPublicKeyStr);

                // Log owner account public key
                LOGGER.info("Owner account public key: " + ownerPublicKey);

                Account mintAccount = new Account();
                PublicKey mintPublicKey = mintAccount.getPublicKey();

                // Log mint account public key
                LOGGER.info("Mint account public key: " + mintPublicKey.toString());
                Transaction transaction = new Transaction();

                long lamportsForRentExemption = getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption();

                TransactionInstruction createAccountInstruction = SystemProgram.createAccount(
                        ownerPublicKey,
                        mintPublicKey,
                        lamportsForRentExemption,
                        TokenProgram.MINT_LAYOUT_SIZE,
                        TokenProgram.PROGRAM_ID
                );

                byte[] data = ByteBuffer.allocate(9)
                        .order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN)
                        .put((byte) 0) // InitializeMint instruction index for the Token Program
                        .putLong(initialSupply)
                        .array();

                AccountMeta mintAccountMeta = new AccountMeta(mintPublicKey, false, true);
                AccountMeta ownerAccountMeta = new AccountMeta(ownerPublicKey, true, false);

                TransactionInstruction mintInstruction = new TransactionInstruction(
                        TokenProgram.PROGRAM_ID,
                        Arrays.asList(mintAccountMeta, ownerAccountMeta),
                        data
                );

                transaction.addInstruction(createAccountInstruction);
                transaction.addInstruction(mintInstruction);

                // Log details of the transaction instructions
                LOGGER.info("Transaction instructions added:");
                logTransactionInstruction(createAccountInstruction);
                logTransactionInstruction(mintInstruction);

                return sendTransaction(transaction, mintAccount)
                        .onItem().transform(signature -> {
                            LOGGER.info("Transaction successful with signature: " + signature);
                            return signature;
                        })
                        .onFailure().invoke(e -> {
                            LOGGER.error("Transaction failed", e);
                        });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed to create brand tokens", e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to create brand tokens", e);
            }
        });
    }

    public Uni<String> sendTransaction(Transaction transaction, Account signer) throws IOException {
        Account feePayerAccount = new Account(Base58.decode(retrievePrivateKey())); // Load fee payer account
        List<Account> signers = Arrays.asList(feePayerAccount, signer);
        Uni<String> uni = Uni.createFrom().item(() -> {
            try {
                String signature = client.getApi().sendTransaction(transaction, signers);
                LOGGER.info("Transaction sent with signature: " + signature);
                return signature;
            } catch (RpcException e) {
                LOGGER.error("Failed to send transaction", e);
                throw new RuntimeException("Failed to send transaction", e);
            }
        });

        // Force subscription and handle errors
        uni.subscribe().with(
                signature -> LOGGER.info("Transaction successful with signature: " + signature),
                failure -> {
                    LOGGER.error("Transaction failed", failure);
                    throw new RuntimeException("Transaction failed", failure);
                }
        );

        return uni;
    }

    private void logTransactionInstruction(TransactionInstruction instruction) {
        LOGGER.info("Instruction program id: " + instruction.getProgramId().toString());
        instruction.getKeys().forEach(key -> {
            LOGGER.info("AccountMeta public key: " + key.getPublicKey().toString());
            LOGGER.info("Is signer: " + key.isSigner());
            LOGGER.info("Is writable: " + key.isWritable());
        });
    }

    private long getMinimumBalanceForRentExemption() {
        // Implement this method to return the minimum balance required for rent exemption.
        return 2039280; // Example value, replace with actual calculation
    }

  
    public static class TokenProgram {
        public static final int MINT_LAYOUT_SIZE = 82;
        public static final PublicKey PROGRAM_ID = new PublicKey("TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb");
    }

